# How would I allow an application running on Tomcat access to a network directory?

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-7, windows-services

I'm running a web application (written in Java) on a Tomcat server running on Windows 7. At some point in the application, I try to access a directory on a remote machine through the basic java.io.File class.

If I start Tomcat from the command line through "tomcat6.exe //TS//MyServiceName", my application can successfully find the network directory. When I start Tomcat as a service, though, it thinks the directory doesn't exist.

Based on some research, I'm assuming it's an authentication issue. I've updated the windows service to "Log on as" my domain user account, and I've updated the tomcat service to add a username and password with 'tomcat6.exe //US//MyServiceName --User="bhardage" --Password="xxx"', but even with both of these changes it still doesn't find the network directory.

I've also tried 'tomcat6.exe //US//MyServiceName --User="mydomain\\bhardage" --Password="xxx"' with no luck.

Would anyone be able to tell me the proper way to get my web application running under a different user?

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks,

B.J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seemed to be some problems with the "Log on as" feature. Maybe these problems still exist.

You can try to set the user account via the properties of the tomcat service in the windows service manager.

Here is a [description](http://blog.justinmiranda.com/2007/05/running-tomcat-55x-service-as-another.html) how to do that. Look at attempt number 3. It is based on an old version of tomcat (5.5) but it should work the same way.

Edit:

Maybe your network directory is not mapped when the service starts tomcat. This may be because the user logs on in a separate logon act.

Try to execute a "net use" command before accessing the network directory. This can be done with:

```
Runtime.exec("net use Z: \\\\My\\Share")
```

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. I've actually already set the "Log on as" property in the Windows service manager, with no success.

Comment: Hmm thats strange. I think I also had that issue some time age. As far as I remember that was the way to fix it. Have you also restarted the service afterwards?

Comment: Yeah, I've restarted the service a few times with no change. It still works if I start it from the command line, but not if I start it from the Windows service manager.

Comment: I've updated the answer with another possibility. Maybe the share is not mapped in the fresh service login when not starting via command line.

Comment: I tried that with no change. I didn't execute it from my code, but I executed it from the command line immediately before accessing the network directory

Comment: Well, but the service gets a new login session and maybe the network resource in the session the service gets?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9428/discussion-between-david-dionis-and-benny)

Comment: So I wasn't able to solve it on my local machine for whatever reason (probably user error somewhere), but we were able to get it working on the client's machine, using the steps mentioned by you and Kevin.

Answer (score 1):

The "Log on" has to work (I have used it quite a few times), as long as that account has the necessary right to the network share.

When you start it from the command line, and it works, are you logged in as "bhardage" ?

Now, when you start it up as a service, which account do you see tomcat running under in task manager ?

Comment: When I open Process Explorer, I can see that tomcat6.exe is running under "mydomain\bhardage". When I open a command prompt (to run tomcat from the command line), that too is running under "mydomain\bhardage". If it's not a permissions problem, I'm not sure what the problem could be but I guess I'll have to look into it more

Comment: How are you accessing the network share ? Is it using \\some_machine\some_share or using a drive letter (like X:) ?

Comment: I'm trying to access it through a mapped folder, i.e. a drive letter

Comment: The mapped drive piece is setup at logon. Not 100% sure whether it would work as a service. It possible try the "\\some_machine\some_share" notation and see if that works. First try it from the command line and when it works, attempt the same via a service.

Comment: So I wasn't able to solve it on my local machine for whatever reason (probably user error somewhere), but we were able to get it working on the client's machine, using the steps mentioned by you and David. I'm going to give the answer to David, since he was the first to respond